# R, how to select the rows having the smallest sums in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I've a matrix made of real numbers, and I'd like to select the K rows that have the lowest sum.
For example, in this case, if we wanted the smallest 2 rows, I'd like to select column 3 and column 8.

```
1 |   8.986971   57.2683300     72.059794   29.1323883    0.14323922
2 |  32.132388    2.8567608      3.986971   55.2683300   68.05979444
3 |   0.268330    1.0597944      0.132388    0.8567608    0.01302869
4 |   3.856761    1.9869713     48.268330   71.0597944   28.13238834
5 |   0.059794   25.1323883      7.143239    5.9869713   52.26832996
6 |   8.986971   46.2683300     61.059794   29.1323883    5.14323922
7 |  32.132388    8.1432392      4.013029   55.2683300   70.05979444
8 |   0.268330    0.0597944      1.132388    0.8567608    2.98697131
9 |   3.856761    5.0130287     45.268330   71.0597944   23.13238834
10 | 74.059794   18.1323883      9.143239    5.9869713   54.26832996
```

Which command should I use in R to do all this?

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: I am not sure what you really want, do you want to identify columns and rows which at the same time will have the lowest sum?

Comment: Add a "sum" column, sort it, retreive the rows you want

Comment: `x[rank(rowSums(x)) <= K, ]` where `x` is your matrix

Comment: @eipi10 Please consider to post the comment as a solution and close this.

Comment: As requested...see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the K rows with the smallest row sums:

```
x[rank(rowSums(x)) <= K, ]
```

Where `x` is your matrix.